# How can I draw two contours on an image given a contour distance of 100 pixels between them using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

What I have tried is drawing the external contour using the following lines

```
cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(orig, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3) # this draws the external contour
```

Referring the below
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How can I arrive at the answer below?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Ooh tough. https://answers.opencv.org/question/44580/how-to-resize-a-contour/ are solutions in c++. Don't think it would be too hard to convert to a Python solution. I will do this later when I have time. Your algorithm should find center of contour. contour - center. Scale, new contour + center

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize a contour in opencv 2.4.11 python? (Goal: Object extraction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644899/how-to-resize-a-contour-in-opencv-2-4-11-python-goal-object-extraction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it is solved in the links but you can use a blank mask on which you can draw your contour and then use `cv2.dilate` to expand it using a kernel size of the number of pixels you require between them. Once that is done find contours on the mask and draw the second one onto your original image.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('contour.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, cnts, -1, 255, 1)
kernel = np.ones((100, 100), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations = 1)
cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, cnts, 1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank for your solution though I still have something to ask. How can I smoothen the two contours?? @Vardan Agarwal

Comment: Sorry I didn't exactly understand what you mean by smoothing. I guess you don't want to have such jagged edges for which you can simply apply blurring.

Comment: I applied burring but the results looked similar to the results above? Sure those jugged lines/edges are supposed to clear (no noise)